# RichFaces rich:autocomplete not firing valueChangeListener

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets

Based on [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&sample=modes&skin=blueSky) Im implementing a rich:autocomplete with a dynamic list to the autocomplete. What i want to do next is, when the user edits this field to update another field based on its value.

I've found various links and references declaring this is a bug, that it triggers when the form in used is submitted, workaraounds but from at least a year ago. [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/603319), [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/165095) and [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10862).

Fragment of my code:

```
<rich:autocomplete value="#{cotizacionBean.currentOpcionEditable.sumaAsegurada}" style="width:100px;" id="sumaAseguradora"
                              required="true" validatorMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}"
                              autocompleteMethod="#{cotizacionBean.getAutocompleteListSumaAsegurada}"
                              valueChangeListener="#{cotizacionBean.sumaAseguradaModificada}"
                              requiredMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}" converterMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}">
                 </rich:autocomplete>
```

And my bean:

```
public void sumaAseguradaModificada(){
    System.out.println("entro sumaAseguradaModificada");
}
```

So my questions are two: is this already fix? How can i do it?

Comment: Have you found a solution or a workaround for this?

Comment: Nop not yet, just used another jsf tag. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got that to work:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="submitSearch"
    execute="sumaAseguradora"
    render="sumaAseguradora"
    action="#{cotizacionBean.sumaAseguradaModificada}" />
<rich:autocomplete style="width:100px;" id="sumaAseguradora"
    required="true" validatorMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}"
    autocompleteMethod="#{cotizacionBean.getAutocompleteListSumaAsegurada}"
    requiredMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}" converterMessage="#{msgs['global.etiqueta.sumaAseguradoraRequerida']}"
    onselectitem="submitSearch()"
    value="#{cotizacionBean.currentOpcionEditable.sumaAsegurada}">
</rich:autocomplete>
```

In the Bean, I had to change the signature of the method:

```
public Object sumaAseguradaModificada() {
   System.out.println("entro sumaAseguradaModificada");
   return "success";
}
```